# Is there a possibility to extend digitalocean droplet disk size with volumes?

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

DO droplets general plans are very good but are very low in terms of disk space. So I bought a plan with enough CPU and RAM but disk space is still very low even if I choose x2 SSD.

Is there a possibility to extend droplet disk size with volumes?

I understood that the volumes are like some external disks, but is there any possibility with their help to expand the space of the primary disk?